# Pass Array value in cucumber .feature file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, automated-tests, gherkin

I want to pass array value as a parameter from cucumber .feature file, so I can access it from step definition file:

I am using this format:

```
Examples:
|r1|t1|
|abc|[aa,bb,cc]|
```

But I'm getting an error 
`undefined method`each' for "[aa,bb,cc]":String (NoMethodError)`

Is it possible to pass array from .feature file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you need the square brackets.

```
When I pass this array "aa,bb,cc"
```

You have to split your string up.

```
When(/I pass this array "([^"]*)"$/) do |array|
  array.split(',').each{|entry| do something }
end
```

Note: you may want to strip the entries in case there is whitespace around them `{|entry| puts entry.strip }`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to put square brackets in Examples. Just write the values as comma separated e.g.

`When I expect the messages to contain a,b,c,d`

And in your step definition file, use the below code:

```
  When(/^I expect the messages to contain (.*)+$/,
  { timeout },
  async rules => {
    const rulesArray = rules.split(',');
    rulesArray.forEach(rule => {
      ## write your logic
    });
  }
);
```